# embeding a facebook 'like' button

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-like

I **Know** this is super simple but for the life of me i cant seem to figure out why it refuses to work.. if use the like plugin generator http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ and from that got this iframe `<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lightandspace.co.uk%2F&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=400&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=arial&amp;height=35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:400px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>`

what happens is that it says it cant load the page as if the link is broken but i dont know why ??

Ive also tryed the js/html5 method but that just fails to display at all.

any helps much apreciated

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In your iframe code:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/
```

Are you sure that isn't supposed to be:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/
```

Comment: no, using '//' will maintain the current page's method (i.e HTTP or HTTPS)

Comment: Also, OP, that page seems to load OK for me when I open it in a [new tab](https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lightandspace.co.uk%2F&amp%3Bsend=false&amp%3Blayout=standard&amp%3Bwidth=400&amp%3Bshow_faces=false&amp%3Baction=like&amp%3Bcolorscheme=light&amp%3Bfont=arial&amp%3Bheight=35)

Comment: No, "//" will load over HTTPS if the site is HTTPS, HTTP if it's HTTP. Perfectly valid, not sure why the OP accepted this.

Answer (score 0):

I created a jsFiddle for this at http://jsfiddle.net/JkZna/, and it seems to work. Could you add the location of your website and the exact error generated?

Note that you cannot run the Facebook plugin as is locally.